# Are seasons capitalised?

Tags: orthography, capitalization

I'm not sure how many people share this experience, but I've personally grown up being taught to spell the seasons with a capital heading, e.g. *Spring, Summer, Autumn, Winter.*

Yet, when I type the seasons with a capital in Microsoft Word, I'm given the blue squiggly line under them, telling me to use *spring* (or *summer, autumn, winter*).

Have I been taught incorrectly, or is this a MS Word error?

Comment: http://grammar.about.com/od/punctuationandmechanics/a/Guidelines-For-Using-Capital-Letters.htm


Read point no.15

Comment: It's a style issue.  I can recall in about 3rd grade (ie, a long time ago) that we were taught that "Autumn" was capitalized but "fall" was not (nor was "winter", "spring", or "summer", IIRC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Seasons are not capitalized.** There are only a few exceptions, off the top of my head:

> 1. When used as a proper noun (I.E. The Summer Olympics).
> 2. When used in a title (I.E. *A Guide To Spring Cleaning!*).
> 3. Or, obviously, at the beginning of a sentence.

Cheers :)

Comment: Capitalisation is perfectly correct according to British English. American English uses -ize instead -ise like- organize vs organise, realise vs realize. You will get underlind -ise if you set keyboard layout to be English(US)

Comment: @Invoker I wasn't aware. Edited post. Sorry dk123!

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. Good to know there are people to help out when you have questions :)